# .Net Core Hosting bundle - v3.0 hosting of v2.1 app?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, .net-core

I'm deploying an ASP .net core app to a new a new windows server 2016 instance. 
The app was developed to use .net core 2.1.1
The server is setup to use the latest .NET Core Hosting Bundle v3.0.0
Is this setup ok? Is .net core backwards compatable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The app was developed to use .net core 2.1.1 The server is setup to use the latest .NET Core Hosting Bundle v3.0.0 Is this setup ok?

No! its not okay! because `.NET Core 3.0` has lot of breaking changes which breaks existing .NET Core 2.1 app. So you have to install the [.NET Core Hosting Bundle 2.1.1](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.1)  separately.

Comment: Are they ok to install side by side? (i.e. just run the hosting bundle over the top of the existing v3.0.0)

Comment: Yes! It is fine to install side by side.